# What is the impact of 18th to 19th century colonialism on the live of the common people of the colonial empires

Tags: colonization, economy, social-class, imperialism, land

This topic suddenly came to me when I was doing my homework. I went online to search but most of the articles only talked about the impacts on the country or place that was being colonized.

According to what I have learned, colonies in 18th and 19th centuries were regarded as a place to supply raw materials for the home nation's industrial development. However, these benefits were only usable by the industrial capitalists...right?

What other social, economical, political impact does colonialism have on the common people of the home nation(majority of the society, espcially the lower class)? Does colonialism,and essentially, other land claims for resource benefit the majority(of the home nation, of the world)?

Comment: No, I mean the common people in Britain, France, and all other colonial Empires' mainland. Did their nation's colonialism bring any improvement for them?

Comment: Re "...these benefits were only usable by the industrial capitalists...":   Who do you suppose gets jobs working for the "industrial capitalists", making things out of those raw materials?  And who do you suppose uses their wages to buy the things the "industrial capitalists" build?

Comment: The British commoner got tea to drink...